# How do I render a node returned by the Drupal search module?

Tags: 7, theming, search

I'm using Drupal 7 to build a fairly simple directory site. I'm trying to theme my search results page the same as a taxonomy page, but as you may know, the results arrive by a completely different process in those two situations. I've copied the `search-result.tpl.php` file from the Search module to my own theme, and am trying to take advantage of the `$result` variable returned by the module. However, it doesn't seem to be as simple as `print render($result);`

I tried to isolate the relevant `node` object within `$result` and perform `render()` on it, like so:

> ```
> $content=Array(); $content['#node'] = $result['node'];
> print render($content);
> ```

But that just throws an error (can't use object as array) or simply returns nothing.

`$result['node']` definitely contains the fields I want to echo on the page, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prepare a view for the node object:

```
$view_mode = 'teaser'; // Or whatever
$view = node_view($result['node'], $view_mode);
print render($view);
```

Comment: Cheers, Clive! I ended up using `field_attach_view('node', $node, 'teaser')`. Is this a similar function? An alias? Is there a reason `node_view` would be better? Let me know and I'll happily update my code/accept your answer.

Comment: No problem :) I *think* `node_view()` would be better as it prepares the whole view for the node including running preprocess functions/templates etc. In fact if you look at [`node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/7) it internally calls [`node_build_content()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_build_content/7) which in turn actually calls `field_attach_prepare_view` (and others), and invokes the `entity_view` hook for all modules. During that hook I believe `field_attach_view()` is called anyway

Comment: So I think the answer is, if you want the fully rendered/templated teaser node the use `node_view()`. If you just want the node content you should probably call `node_build_content()` and if you're just interested in the *fields* you should use `field_attach_view()`. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Yes, makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: By the way, I needed to say `node_view($result['node'],'teaser')` instead of simply naming a `$view_mode` variable. An edit might be in order.

Comment: @IsaacLubow Very sorry about that you're totally right, I've made the edit